# zip command keeps including the entire parent directory structure

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zip

I am trying to run this zip command on an Ubuntu WSL: `zip -r /home/chansen/db-backup/backup.zip /mnt/c/data/db/*`

I want the zip to contain all contents of `db` at the top level, but the resulting zip has those files nested inside all the parent directories. The zip file contains: `mnt > c > data > db > myFiles`. I just want the myFiles part to be at the top level without all those parent directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to `cd` into the db directory, then run your zip command using a relative path, like this:

```
cd /mnt/c/data/db/
zip -r /home/chansen/db-backup/backup.zip ./*
```

Comment: Wow, alright thanks! I didn't know the CWD actually mattered, I thought it just uses the last part of the path as the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `-j` option. Below is from the `zip` man page

```
   -j
   --junk-paths
          Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default,  zip
          will store the full path (relative to the current directory).
```

so in you case, you would do this

```
zip -r -j /home/chansen/db-backup/backup.zip /mnt/c/data/db/*
```